# Como recuperar os dados do checkbox como "checked"?

Tags: php, laravel, checkbox

**Contexto:**

Estou criando o método de **"Atualizar Estrutura"**, dependendo do modelo selecionado os itens devem vim marcados no **CheckBox**. Mas, por algum motivo não está funcionando. Como solucionar este problema?
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Método edita do Controlador ChecklistController.php:**

```
  //Método que redireciona para a página de atualizar o checklistEstrutura
    public function edita($id)
    {

        $checklistEstrutura = DB::table('checklist_estrutura')
        ->join('checklist_modelo', 'checklist_modelo.id', '=', 'checklist_estrutura.modelo_id')
        ->join('checklist_itens', 'checklist_itens.id', '=', 'checklist_estrutura.itens_id')
        ->select('checklist_itens.id')
        ->where('modelo_id','=', $id)
        ->groupBy('checklist_estrutura.estrutura_id', 'checklist_itens.descricao_item')
        ->distinct()
        ->get(); 

        $checklistEstruturaArray = $checklistEstrutura->toArray(); 


        $checklistEstruturaModelo =  ChecklistEstrutura::where('modelo_id', '=', $id)->first();
        $modeloId = $checklistEstruturaModelo->modelo_id;

        return view('admin.checklistEstrutura.edita', ['checklistEstruturaModelo' =>$modeloId, 'checklistsModelos' => ChecklistModelo::all(),
        'checklistsItens' =>  ChecklistItem::all(), 'checklistsEstruturas' =>  $checklistEstruturaArray ]);
    }
```

**Resultado do Debug da variável "$checklistEstruturaArray"**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Página edita.blade.php**

Este trecho do código verifica se o $checklistItemArray está no array $checklistsEstruturas. Em caso positivo ele seta o comboBox. Mas, não funcionou.

> {{ in_array($checklistItem , $checklistsEstruturas)  ? 'checked' :
>   ''}}

```
@section('content')
<div class="page-content">
        <div class="panel">
            <div class="panel-body container-fluid">
        @include('admin.includes.alerts')
        <form method="POST" action="{{ route('checklistEstrutura.atualiza') }}">
        <font color="black">
        {{csrf_field()}}

        <div class="row form-group">

                <input type="hidden" name="id" value="{{$checklistEstruturaModelo}}">

                <div class="col-md-4">
                     <label for="inputName" class="control-label">Modelo</label>
                     <select type="text" class="form-control" name="modelo_id" id="modelo_id" >
                     <option value="">Selecione</option>
                                @foreach($checklistsModelos as $checklistModelo)
                                <option value="{{$checklistModelo->id}}" {{$checklistModelo->id == $checklistEstruturaModelo ? 'selected' : ''}}>{{$checklistModelo->modelo}}</option>
                                @endforeach              
                     </select>
                </div> 
        </div>     
         <div class="row form-group col-md-12">
          <label>Itens</label>
          <br/>  <br/>


              @foreach($checklistsItens as $checklistItem)


                            <div class="col-md-12">
                                <div class="checkbox-custom">
                                    <input type="checkbox" name="itens_id[]" value="" {{ in_array($checklistItem , $checklistsEstruturas)  ? 'checked' : ''}}  />
                                    <label for="inputUnchecked">{{$checklistItem->descricao_item}}</label>
                                </div>
                            </div>


              @endforeach

         </div>


            <div class="text-right">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary"><i class="fa fa-floppy-o" aria-hidden="true"></i> Salvar</button>
                <a href="{{route('admin.checklistEstrutura')}}" class="btn btn-default"><i class="fa fa-ban" aria-hidden="true"></i> Cancelar</a>
            </div>
            </font>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
@stop
```

**Modelo E.R do banco de dados:**
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Modelo ChecklistEstrutura.php**

```
<?php


namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use DB;


class ChecklistEstrutura extends Model
{
    protected $table = "checklist_estrutura";

    protected $primaryKey = 'Estrutura_id';

    public $incrementing = false;

    public $timestamps = false; 

    public function checklistEstrutura()
    {
    // return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\ChecklistEstrutura', 'estrutura_id','modelo_id', 'itens_id');
    return $this->belongsTo(ChecklistEstrutura::class, 'Estrutura_id','modelo_id', 'itens_id');
    }

    //Este método salva os dados do Checklist da Estrutura
      public function salvar(ChecklistEstrutura $checklistEstrutura) : Array
      {
         $checklistEstrutura = $this->save();

           if($checklistEstrutura){

              return[
                  'success' => true,
                  'message' => 'Sucesso ao cadastrar'
              ];   
          }
          else{

              return[
                  'success' => false,
                  'message' => 'Falha ao cadastrar'
              ]; 
          }
      }


      //Este método remove os dados do Checklist da Estrutura
    public function deletar(ChecklistEstrutura $checklistEstrutura) : Array
    {
        $checklistEstrutura =  $this->delete();
        if($checklistEstrutura){

            return[
                'success' => true,
                'message' => 'Sucesso ao excluir'
            ];   
        }
        else{

            return[
                'success' => false,
                'message' => 'Falha ao excluir'
            ]; 
        }
    }


  //Este método atualiza os dados do  Checklist da Estrutura
  public function alterar(ChecklistEstrutura $checklistEstrutura) : Array
  {
    $checklistEstrutura = $this->save();
      if($checklistEstrutura){
          return[
              'success' => true,
              'message' => 'Sucesso ao atualizar'
          ];   
      }
      else{
          return[
              'success' => false,
              'message' => 'Falha ao atualizar'
          ]; 
      }
  }
}
```

> Observação: os dados que  devem estar com o "checked" estão na tabela de
>   relação Checklist_Estrutura. Logo estou consultando todos os itens
>   cadastrados na tabela de "checklist_itens" e comparando os dados dos
>   itens que estão cadastrados na tabela Checklist_Estrutura.

Comment: Amiga o Laravel tem um método para facilitar esse tipo de tratamento, dá uma olhada na documentação do método sync(); Se você relacionar corretamente os models, você consegue utilizar o método sync();  sem problemas.
https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-relationships

Comment: Obrigada, irei olhar a documentação.

Answer (score 1):

Vou tentar explicar de uma forma simples, como você deve fazer para conseguir utilizar o método sync().

> O *Model* abaixo será responsável por sua tabela 'checklist_itens'.

```
class Item extends Model {

    protected $_table = 'checklist_itens';

    public function checklist() {
        return $this->belongsToMany( Modelo::class, 'checklist_estrutura' ); // 1 Parâmetro é o model que será relacionado, 2 parâmetro é a tabela intermediária 
    }

}
```

> O *Model* abaixo será responsável por sua tabela 'checklist_modelo'.

```
class Modelo extends Model {

    protected $_table = 'checklist_modelo';

    public function checklist() {
        return $this->belongsToMany( Item::class, 'checklist_estrutura' ); 
    }

}
```

No seu método de atualizar você vai utilizar o seguinte.

```
public function editar( Request $request, $id ) {
    $fields = $request->all();
    $modelo = Modelo::find( $id ); //

    // "checklist" que a gente está chamando aqui é o método que definimos no Model: Modelo
    $modelo->checklist()->sync( $fields['itens_id'] ); // Esse método recebe um array com os ID`s.
}
```

<sub>O método sync() já faz todo o tratamento para verificar se existe ou não o relacionamento, se existir ele remove se não ele cria.</sub>

Comment: Olá Kayo Bruno, ao tentar implementar a sua sugestão ocorreu o seguinte erro: Undefined index: itens_id

Comment: itens_id é pra ser o array com os ids marcados no checkbox

Comment: Eu entendi, mas  o laravel não está reconhecendo.

Comment: Seu método editar, além de receber o $id ele precisa receber um request. Está dessa forma?

Comment: Sim, está da seguinte forma:  public function edita($id, Request $request). E  a rota está definida assim:   $this->get('edita/{id}','ChecklistEstruturaController@edita')->name('checklistEstrutura.edita');

Comment: O método da rota não pode ser GET pois se trata de uma atualização, o correto deve ser PUT.

Comment: Olá, corrigi a rota e troquei o método GET por PUT. Mas ocorreu o seguinte erro: MethodNotAllowedHttpException

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/83698/discussion-between-ruama-and-kayo-bruno).